# TestFlight Beta not showing testers

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

Big hand to Apple for screwing TestFlight. I can't seem to get anything to happen past this screen. I've

1. Created external testers
2. Upload a build with ad hoc profile (though application loader)
3. Turned on TestFlight Beta Testing (even tried turning it on and off to get invitation emails to send)

When adding external users they never receive and email either. Anyone have this problem?

[image]

Comment: How's it a problem that only Apple can address? Maybe someone else has ran into this and found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this exact message, but one problem I see with your process is that you used an adhoc profile.  According to Apple, you should be using an app store distribution profile:

> Generate a new App Store Distribution profile containing the beta
>   entitlement to distribute builds via TestFlight.

As the message says, you also need to have the beta entitlement in your profile.  If you created it in the last couple months - it should have it - but it's possible adhoc profiles don't.  When you go to upload the binary, expand the entitlements and check to see that beta-reports-active is present and set to on.

Hopefully one of those two is your issue.

Comment: That did it! What's weird is I upload an app with an Ad Hoc profile a couple of weeks ago and it worked fine. Not sure what's going on here but changing to a distribution profile worked.